# Solutions to nonlinear PDE derived from the Dirichlet energy in the stereographic plane

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Define a complex valued function $z$ in the stereographic plane and let $z=z(s,s^{*})$ for $s$ a complex valued variable and $*$ denoting the complex conjugate.

Define the Dirichlet energy as

$$ \int \frac{\lvert z_s \rvert^{2} + \lvert z_{s^{*}} \rvert^{2}}{(1 + \lvert z \rvert^{2})^{2}} \ ds ds^*. $$

Minimizing this with respect to $z^*$ we find that $z$ must satisfy the following nonlinear PDE:

$$(1 + \lvert z \rvert^{2}) z_{s s^*} = 2 z^{*} z_s z_{s^{*}}. $$

Some simple solutions to this are $z = f(s)$ or $z = g(s^{*})$
for arbitrary functions $f, g$.

Are there other known solutions to this equation?

Edit added: Are these solutions related to the spherical harmonics? If so, how can we compose two solutions in the stereographic plane to find another solution?

I see reference to this equation [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.08923.pdf), but cannot find other useful references. Any tips on work that has been done on this equation are appreciated.